# Spring Autowire within Method

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3, autowired

My application has a interface as below.

```
public interface MainInterface
{
     void someMethod();
}
```

Then, i have number of implementations of this interface.

```
@Service    
public class ImplClass1 implements MainInterface
{
   @Override
   public void someMehtod()
   {
      //Execution of code
   }
}

@Service    
public class ImplClass2 implements MainInterface
{
   @Override
   public void someMehtod()
   {
      //Execution of code
   }
}

@Service
public class ImplClass3 implements MainInterface
{
   @Override
   public void someMehtod()
   {
      //Execution of code
   }
}
```

Below is a controller.

```
@Controller
public class MainController
{
     MainInterface implObj;

     @RequestMapping("service1")
     public void Service1Handler()
     {
         //Replace below with @Autowire
         implObj = new ImplClass1();
     }

     @RequestMapping("service2")
     public void Service1Handler()
     {
         //Replace below with @Autowire
         implObj = new ImplClass2();
     }

     @RequestMapping("service3")
     public void Service1Handler()
     {
         //Replace below with @Autowire
         implObj = new ImplClass3();
     }
}
```

As mentioned in comment of each method i want to initialize it using spring.
This is just an example. In my real time application i have 12 implementations of a interface and 6 methods in a controller.

Can you please guide how can i use autowire feature at method level or suggest any other best way around.

Thanks

Comment: I fear that, controller would be sigletone and you have made your interface an instance of the controller and you want to change implementation in each method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can think of these two ways -

```
@Controller
public class MainController
{
     @Autowired @Qualifier("impl1") MainInterface impl1;
     @Autowired @Qualifier("impl2") MainInterface impl2;
     @Autowired @Qualifier("impl3") MainInterface impl3;

     @RequestMapping("service1")
     public void service1Handler()
     {
          impl1.doSomething()
     }

     @RequestMapping("service2")
     public void Service1Handler()
     {
         //Replace below with @Autowire
          impl2.doSomething()
     }

     @RequestMapping("service3")
     public void Service1Handler()
     {
         //Replace below with @Autowire
           impl3.doSomething()
     }
}
```

OR hide it behind a factory:

```
class MaintenanceInterfaceFactory{
     @Autowired @Qualifier("impl1") MainInterface impl1;
     @Autowired @Qualifier("impl2") MainInterface impl2;
     @Autowired @Qualifier("impl3") MainInterface impl3;
     getImplForService(String name){
        //return one of the impls above based on say service name..
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As i said i have 12 implementations of interface so it would be difficult to create 12 class variable according to first option. But your i may follow your second solution. Thanks again !!!